# Rust winit eventloop running too often

Tags: performance, user-interface, rust, event-loop, winit

I have a simple winit application that is creating an empty window and running the EventLoop:

```
event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
    control_flow.set_wait_until(std::time::Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(1000));
    match event {
        Event::WindowEvent{ ref event, window_id, } => {},
        Event::MainEventsCleared => {
            window.request_redraw()
        },
        _ => {}
    }
});
```

On MacOS this process uses 100% of 1 core of CPU. If I remove the window.request_redraw call, or when I artificially limit with a thread sleep (regardless of setting wait until to control flow), the CPU usage falls dramatically to about 10%. This suggests that wait/wait until are not working correctly because I expect to only see calls to request_redraw every 1 second if I understood correctly.

Is there any way to limit the event loop run frequency other than thread::sleep/wait/wait until, or I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: Maybe using `control_flow.set_wait_until(std::time::Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(10))` will solve your problem. You could also try using `control_flow.set_wait()` if your application doesn't need to be redrawn every 10ms (100Hz).

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem with the code you posted, are you sure this is a [mre]?

Comment: @ThomasSaint-Gérand I tried several variations of that, and while that seems to work for the original empty event loop, it still doesn't work if I add some work in MainEventsCleared.

Comment: I think you can solve your problem by having your rendering code in a `RedrawRequested` match arm and by removing your call to `window.request_redraw()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`WaitUntil`](https://docs.rs/winit/latest/winit/event_loop/enum.ControlFlow.html#variant.WaitUntil) causes:

> When the current loop iteration finishes, suspend the thread until either another event arrives or the given time is reached.

and [`request_redraw`](https://docs.rs/winit/latest/winit/window/struct.Window.html#method.request_redraw)

> Emits a `Event::RedrawRequested` event

so unless I'm missing something everything works as expected.

Because `request_redraw` causes an event to be emitted, the event loop immediately starts the next iteration.

Also calling that method explicitly shouldn't be required since after [`MainEventsCleared`](https://docs.rs/winit/0.28.7/winit/event/enum.Event.html#variant.MainEventsCleared)

> `Event::RedrawRequested`, [...] gets emitted immediately

Limiting that frequency artificialy will only cause a sluggish feel about your app which then could not immediately respond to events, so I doubt that's what you want. As far as I know `winit` doesn't provide such a feature (aside from the mentioned `set_wait` / `set_wait_until`).

Comment: This explains it and works after removing request_redraw, thank you.